# In GWT-app, how can I close an IFrame using the response from a doPost

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe

In my GWT app I receive payments through Recurly, with Recurly's page in an IFrame. When Recurly has successfully processed the payment their page redirects to a success URL that I provide, which hits my servlet with a `POST`. After receiving the `POST` I want to close the IFrame and perform operations on my widgets. I close the IFrame using javascript in the response:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    /* other code */
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    buf.append("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
    buf.append("var n = window.parent.document.getElementById(\"recurly-popup\");");
    buf.append("n.parentNode.removeChild(n);");
    buf.append("</script>");
    response.getOutputStream().print(buf.toString());
}
```

However, I can't seem to find any way to detect on the client when the IFrame is closed. How can I detect it using GWT or GWTQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a Javascript listener (via GWT's JSNI).  The listener needed for FF and IE browsers is documented here: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/627389-having-trouble-event-listener-detect-iframe-close-event-fromparent

Another option to consider might be executing a javascript function (e.g. sending an event) on the parent, before you remove the iframe.  Something like:

```
buf.append("<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">");
buf.append("window.parent.document.myGWTJSNIFunction('recurly_processed_event');");
buf.append("var n = window.parent.document.getElementById(\"recurly-popup\");");
buf.append("n.parentNode.removeChild(n);");
buf.append("</script>");
```

Apologies if the Javascript is incorrect, it has not been tested.  More details on GWT JSNI here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html